# EF Core generating queries on page load

Tags: asp.net-identity, razor-pages, ef-core-3.1

So I'm building a membership portal that uses Identity and with it come EF Core. I have turned on query logging so that I can see what entity does to try and optimize queries, and in doing so I have noticed some queries that seem to fire every time I have a page load, and I am trying to track the reasons. The log is as follows:

```
  SELECT TOP(1) (All columns in the table)
  FROM [Portal].[User] AS [u]
  WHERE [u].[Id] = @__p_0

  SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[ClaimType], [u].[ClaimValue], [u].[UserId]
  FROM [Identity].[UserClaim] AS [u]
  WHERE [u].[UserId] = @__user_Id_0

  SELECT [r].[Name]
  FROM [Identity].[UserRole] AS [u]
  INNER JOIN [Identity].[Role] AS [r] ON [u].[RoleId] = [r].[Id]

  SELECT TOP(1) [r].[Id], [r].[ConcurrencyStamp], [r].[Name], [r].[NormalizedName]
  FROM [Identity].[Role] AS [r]
  WHERE [r].[NormalizedName] = @__normalizedName_0

  SELECT [r].[ClaimType], [r].[ClaimValue]
  FROM [Identity].[RoleClaim] AS [r]
  WHERE [r].[RoleId] = @__role_Id_0
```

From what I can tell, these are maybe something to do with authorization (I am using authorize data attributes). I seems a bit sloppy that all these queries happen, and then if I want some user data, I have to query again. It should be noted that these tend to happen when a user is signed in.

Does anyone know where these could be coming from, and if I should just ignore them?

Thanks

Comment: If you have configured SecurityStampValidatorOptions in startup, make sure ValidationInterval is not set to TimeSpan.Zero or any other lower value, it causes to fetch data from Identity Tables on every http request.

Comment: That is exactly what I have done. We have a CRM integration that can turn user access off so I update the security stamp in a webhook. I never put the 2 together, so thank you for this!